# In the format of date and time in php, the timing is not correct

Tags: php

When I am fetching the date n time using this function:

```
date("d-M-Y h:i A");
```

It gives the wrong timing. 
The current correct timing is 04.30 pm but my function is showing 11.00 am.
That means showing 5.30 hours early.
help me out to fetch the correct timing.

Comment: Have you set your timezone in the php.ini and/or for the DateTime-object?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your username, I think you're from India.

So put `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');`

right before `date("d-M-Y h:i A");`

OR

```
$offset= strtotime("+5 hours 30 minutes"); 
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$offset);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two probable causes.

1) The timezone.
2) The server time.

These are actually related.

Check the server time (ie the system time on the machine running the code). If it's incorrect; fix it. If it's correct, then check the timezone also and reference it against the default timezone on the php side.

Answer (score 0):

If working on localhost, change your time zone in your php.ini file.

`OR` try folowing way:

```
<?php
  $timezone = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata" );
  $date = new DateTime();
 $date->setTimezone($timezone );
 echo  $date->format( 'H:i:s A  /  D, M jS, Y' );
?>
```

Comment: i have checked on localhost and also on the server.
but showing wrong time.
wat could be the possible reasons?

Comment: @atultyagi Are you using any variable which stores time?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are getting the UTC time instead of your timezone (which is +5:30 from GMT). (This could be because your default timezone could be set to UTC)

Try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$temp= strtotime("+5 hours 30 minutes"); 
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$temp);
echo $date;
```